# Is "definacy" a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, definite-articles, concept

I came across this word "**definacy**" in an article by a grammarian who uses it to refer to the quality brought about by the definite article in English. Problem is I can't find this word in any dictionary, not even the OED.

[image]

[Source: COPYRIGHT: © Cambridge University Press 1995](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0266078400008257)

If this is a misspelling what is the correct term for it?

Comment: I can't find it either. It may be a 'mountweazel'.

Comment: Googling for the term I find a number of genuine uses, scattered among the misspellings of "deficiency", foreign languages, and porn sites.  It appears to be used in linguistics, British law, and art.

Comment: *definiteness* seems like a better word

Comment: He uses it again later in the article, so it’s not a typo.